# How to enable remote access for the azure VM created in Resource manager

Tags: azure, remote-access, azure-resource-manager

I have created a VM in azure resource manager portal and enabled the Winrm port in the VM. Other than the Session option How can I enable remote access for the VM. Please let me know is there any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with powershell:

```
Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "myRG" -VMName "myVM" -Name "myVMAccessExtension" -ExtensionType "VMAccessAgent" -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" -typeHandlerVersion "2.0" -Location Westus
```

OR

```
  Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName "myRG" -VMName "myVM" -Name "myVMAccess" -Location Westus
```

Or in the portal.azure.com.

[virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/)

Comment: By using Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension how can I can access the VM (For e.g start an exe in the VM remotely using power shell in my local machine).